Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node. using datatable
I'm using datatable and this is my react code, this is giving Failed to execute 'removeChild' every time i make any updates
How to fix it?
I tried using ChatGPT and CaludeAi but none of them worked, I have to use only this datatable.
const columns = [
  { title: "Category", data: "category" },
  { title: "Name", data: "name" },
  { title: "Subscribers", data: "subscribers" },
  { title: "Total News Received", data: "total_news_received" },
];

const Table = ({ selectionRange }) => {
  const tableRef = useRef();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const {
    loading_no_subscribers,
    data,
    news_stats_error,
  } = useSelector((state) => state.GetNoSubscribersReducer);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(GetNoSubscribersAction({ selectionRange }));
  }, [dispatch, selectionRange]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data && data.result) {
      const tableData = [
        ...Object.entries(data?.result?.total_subscribers_service_providers_count).map(([key, value]) => ({
          category: "Service Providers",
          name: key.replace('_', ' '),
          subscribers: value,
          total_news_received: data?.result?.total_news_recieved_service_providers[key] || 0,
        })),
        ...Object.entries(data?.ind).map(([key, value]) => ({
          category: "Industry",
          name: key
          subscribers: value,
          total_news_received: data?.ind[key] || 0,
        })),
        ...Object.entries(data?.tt).map(([key, value]) => ({
          category: "Avasant Subscribers",
          name: key.replace(/^\d+_/, '').replace('_', ' '),
          subscribers: value,
          total_news_received: data?.tt[key] || 0,
        })),
      ];

      if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable(tableRef.current)) {
      
        $(tableRef.current).DataTable().clear().destroy();
        $(tableRef.current).find('tbody').empty();  // Clear the table body
      }

    
      $(tableRef.current).DataTable({
        
        data: tableData,
        columns: columns,
      });
      
    }
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <section>
      <h2 style={{ color: '#136ebd' }}>Subscribers Statistics</h2>
      {loading_no_subscribers ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : news_stats_error ? (
        <p className="text-sm text-red-800">Something went wrong: {news_stats_error}</p>
      ) : (
        <table
          ref={tableRef}
          className="display min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-200 dark:divide-neutral-700 border border-gray-100 dark:border-neutral-300"
          style={{ borderRadius: '7px' }}
        >
          <thead>
            <tr style={{ backgroundColor: '#136ebd' }}>
              <th className="px-6 py-3 text-start text-xs font-medium text-gray-100 uppercase dark:text-neutral-500">Category</th>
              <th className="px-6 py-3 text-start text-xs font-medium text-gray-100 uppercase dark:text-neutral-500">Sub Category</th>
              <th className="px-6 py-3 text-start text-xs font-medium text-gray-100 uppercase dark:text-neutral-500">Subscribers</th>
              <th className="px-6 py-3 text-start text-xs font-medium text-gray-100 uppercase dark:text-neutral-500">Total News Received</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {/* DataTables will populate rows here */}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      )}
    </section>
  );
};

export default Table;


FWIW jquery and React are like oil and water when it comes to UI management and the DOM; it's a React anti-pattern to directly mutate the DOM. I'm not sure what to say other than that you should probably start from scratch and do things the React way, or switch back to regular Javascript if you want to use jquery.

You might have this error because you are populating the rows. Try managing the table state with react useEffect and useState, don't do direct DOM manipulation (from the useRef) and prefer React declarative approach. I'm sure GPT will help you knowing this. Hope it helps.

This was given by ChatGPT only
